# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null while using useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm building an app that needs to access the user's device camera and display the video on the screen. I'm doing it by using a `video` HTML Object and assigning the media stream as its `srcObject`, and it is working as I expected. However, TypeScript is still giving me an error because I'm assigning the `srcObject` property to a possibly null `videoRef.current`.

First, I get the media and assign it to the `videoRef` inside a `useEffect`, like this:

```
const Page: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null)
  const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDeviceMedia = async () => {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true
      })

      setMediaStream(stream)
      videoRef.current!.srcObject = stream
    }
    
    getDeviceMedia()
  }, [])
```

Finally, I return the HTML video assigning its ref to the video ref:

```
return(
  <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted /> 
)
```

The media is displayed on the screen correctly (I can see my camera's video) but TypeScript gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'srcObject')

Am I doing something wrong here or there's a way to go around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a JavaScript error your are getting on execution time. Because when `useEffect`'s callback gets called first time, the JSX may not be rendered yet. Therefore `videoRef.current` is still `null`. Try doing so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getDeviceMedia = async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true
    })
    setMediaStream(stream)
    if(videoRef.current){
      videoRef.current.srcObject = stream
    }
  }
  getDeviceMedia();
},[])
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the dependency array on the question, I had it from the start. Anyway, I tested it using a console.log() and the useEffect is not beeing called infinetely. But your solution worked, when I run it with the if statement it does not give me the error. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. I see, and I updated the answer, removed the part where I was asking to add the dependencies array.